# Grammatical Functions of Resumptive Modifiers and Summative Modifiers

Tags: grammar, parts-of-speech

I am wondering what is the grammatical function of the resumptive modifier (in italics) in the following sentence:

> For several years, the Columbia Broadcasting System created and developed situation comedies that were the best that American TV had to offer, ***comedies*** such as "The Mary Tyler Moore Show" and "All in the Family," ***comedies*** that sparkled with wit and invention.

Is that considered an appositive?

Another question is why there is no conjunction in front of the last **comedies**. (I have never seen a single case where people use conjunctions to connect resumptive modifiers.)

How about the resumptive modifiers in the following sentence? (This time they are adjective clauses.)

> It was Marican writers who first used a vernacular that was both true and lyrical, ***true*** to the rhythms of the working man's speech, **lyrical** in its celebration of the land.

How about the resumptive modifiers in the following sentence? (This time they are verbal clauses.)

> Humans have been defined by some as the only animal that can laugh at grief, ***laugh*** at the pain and tragedy that define their fate.

How about the summative modifier in the following sentence?

> Scientists have finally unraveled the mysteries of the human gene, ***a discovery that*** may lead to the control of such dread diseases as cancer and birth defects.